# Number of real roots of $f(x)=0$

Tags: functions

let f be a deriable function satisfying $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)+2xy-2$ and f'(0)=-2 , then we have to find the number of real roots of f(x)=0 .

my try

putting y=0 I got f(0)=2 .

after that differentiting the given equation

$f'(x+y)=f'(x)f'(y)+2y+2x$

in this substituting y=0 ,

I got x=1 .

but don't get the number of roots .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$ f(0)=f(0+0)=2f(0)-2\tag{1}$$

therefore

$$f(0)=2\tag{2}$$

We are given that

$$ f^\prime(0)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=-2 $$

\begin{eqnarray}
f^\prime(x)&=&\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\\
&=&\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x)+f(h)+2xh-2-f(x)}{h}\\
&=&\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(h)-2}{h}+2x\\
&=&\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}+2x\\
&=&=f^\prime(0)+2x\\
&=&2x-2
\end{eqnarray}

Therefore

$$ f(x)=x^2-2x+f(0)$$

so, from equation $(2)$ we have

$$ f(x)=x^2-2x+2$$

Which has two zeros $1\pm i$.

This is easily checked against the contitions.